# Error de bindparam al ejecutar clase

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer transacciones en ***PHP***. Tengo una clase:

```
public function grabar($fecha) {
try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla1 (cod, nom, :fecha)
        SELECT cod, nom
        FROM tabla2
        WHERE flag1 IS NULL AND flag2 IS NULL";

        $dbh = new ConnectDB();
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $dbh->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR); //-- AQUI SALE EL PROBLEMA
        $dbh->query($sql);
        $dbh->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Se produjo un error: ". $e->getMessage();
        $dbh->rollback();
    }
```

Mi conexión a la base de datos, ConnectDB es:

```
class ConnectDB extends PDO {
    public function __construct () {
try {
    parent:: __construct('mysql:host='.aa.';dbname='.bb.'; charset=utf8', user, pass);
    parent:: setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    parent:: setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die ('La Base de Datos no Existe');
}
```

La invocación a la clase:

```
$ClaseDAO->grabar($fecha);
```

Y $fecha tiene el formato YYYY-MM-DD.

El error que me muestra es: Fatal error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ConexionDB::bindParam() in C:\ruta... \ClaseDAO.class.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\ruta... \controlador.php(216): ClaseDAO->grabar('2021-10-31') #1 C:\ruta... \index.php(12): include('C:\\ruta \\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\ruta... \ClaseDAO.class.php on line 21`

Nota: Para probar quité `$fecha` de la clase y funciona. Así que al parecer el problema está con `$fecha`, pero no entiendo por qué.

Comment: ¿`ConnectDB` extiende de PDO? Conviene que pongas la línea donde declaras las clase.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error *`Call to undefined method ConexionDB::bindParam()`* está ocurriendo porque el método `bindParam()` pertenece al objeto [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) y ese objeto se obtiene con `prepare()` o con `query()`.

Por tanto, debes primero preparar la consulta e invocar a `bindParam()` sobre el objeto resultante de la preparación.

Tú lo estás haciendo al revés, invocando esto al final del todo:

```
$dbh->query($sql);
```

Además, no puedes usar `query()` con consultas preparadas (con marcadores). Y aunque no fuesen con marcadores, dado que estás en un contexto de transacciones, siempre conviene usar `prepare()`, el cual sería más rápido, porque `prepare()` traza un plan de ejecución de la consulta, haciendo que las consultas sucesivas sean mucho más rápidas, cosa que `query()` no hace.

Finalmente, hay que concluir con un `execute()`.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
public function grabar($fecha) {

    try {
            $dbh = new ConnectDB();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla1 (cod, nom, :fecha)
            SELECT cod, nom
            FROM tabla2
            WHERE flag1 IS NULL AND flag2 IS NULL";
            #$stmt será un objeto PDOStatement
            $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
            $dbh->beginTransaction();
            #Invocas bindParam mediante $stmt
            $stmt->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR); //-- AQUI SALE EL PROBLEMA
            #Sin esto la consulta no se ejecutará nunca
            $stmt->execute();
            $dbh->commit();
    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Se produjo un error: ". $e->getMessage();
            $dbh->rollback();
        }
}
```

---

Aparte de eso, conviene tomar en cuenta lo que sigue, a fin de mejorar el código...

Tus tres llamadas a `:.parent` no me convencen. No lo he verificado, pero me parece que sólo puedes hacer una llamada al padre, para pasarle aquello que no puedes asignarle al hijo.

Tampoco me convence los espacios blanco que dejas entre `parent::` y el método. [Ni en el Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) ni en ningún código veo que se dejen espacios en blanco.

Dado que el constructor de PDO admite un último parámetro donde le puedes pasar un array con las configuraciones, intenta esto:

```
class ConexionDB extends PDO {
    public function __construct () {
        try 
        {
            $options=array(
                             PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=> false,
                             PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=> PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                           );
            #No espacio en blanco
            parent::__construct('mysql:host='.aa.';dbname='.bb.'; charset=utf8', user, pass, $options);
        
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Error de conexión";
            return null;
        }
    }
//... Resto de la clase
}
```

En caso de que eso no fuera posible, podrías asignarle esos atributos al hijo. Como dije antes no lo he confirmado, pero, pensando en Java, a `super()` (el constructor del padre), se le llama siempre una sola vez, no varias veces... No tendría sentido varias llamadas.

Comment: Mi conexión anterior funciona bien para todo, igual hice el cambio según tu planteamiento pero obtengo lo mismo. Voy a ampliar mi pregunta pues el mensaje de error es un poco más extenso.

Comment: @Puntay lo único que puede estar pasando entonces es que la conexión sea nula por algún motivo. Prueba algo así: `if ($dbh) { /*Aquí escribes todo el código de consulta, bindParam y demá*/ } else { echo "Conexión no válida"; }`

Comment: Sale el mismo mensaje. Pero si quito el parametro `$fecha` que paso a la clase y solo dejo el `insert` si funciona. El problema es que no acepta el parámetro. Pero no sé por qué.

Comment: @Puntay ya vi tu error, revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: Con los cambios ya no aparece el error pero tampoco realiza el `insert` a pesar de que sí hay registros.

Comment: @Puntay ¿muestra algún error o mensaje ahora?

Comment: @Puntay, faltaba también esto `$stmt->execute();` antes del `commit()`, revisa de nuevo, he corregido el código.

Comment: Funciona, aunque tendré que analizar el código pues no me ha quedado muy claro. Ahora probaré con más parámetros y más transacciones pues ese era solo el primero.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no ha quedado claro? En resumen: tienes que usar `prepare()` y con el objeto que te devuelve ese método usar `bindParam()` y finalmente `execute()` para ejecutar la consulta. Tú lo estabas intentando usar con el objeto de la conexión directamente, lo cual no es posible y además usabas `query()` en lugar de `execute()`. Si observas el enlace del Manual de PHP que pongo en la pregunta verás que, a la izquierda de cada método te dice el objeto al que pertenece ese método. De todos modos, cualquier duda, puedes preguntar... PDO es bastante claro y la doc del Manual también. @Puntay

Comment: @Puntay [revisa algunos métodos aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php). Si analizas por ejemplo a `prepare()`, verás que a la izquierda tiene esto: `PDO::`, mientras que `bindParam()` a la izquierda tiene esto: `PDOStatement::`, tú no puedes por tanto hacer esto: `$dbh->bindParam(...)`, porque `$dbh` es una instancia de PDO, el cual no dispone de ese método. Es como una cadena: PDO te da acceso a PDOStatement y éste te da acceso a bindParam.